# Approximation of a strongly measurable function by a sequence of simple functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $E$ be a normed space.

$(i)$ $f:X \rightarrow E$ is called Borel measurable if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal A$ for all $B \in \mathcal{Bo}(E)$ where $\mathcal{Bo}(E)$ is the $\sigma-algebra$ generated by the metric topology on $E$.

$(ii)$ $f:X \rightarrow E$ is called strongly measurable if $f$ is Borel measurable and $f(X)$ , the range of $f$, is a separable subset of $E$.

$(iii)$ $f:X \rightarrow E$ is called a simple function if $f$ has a finite range.

Lemma. Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $f:X \rightarrow E$ be a simple function. Then

$f$ is strongly measurable $\Leftrightarrow$    $f$ is Borel measurable.

In the light of the above lemma, my question is the following:

**A New Question: How to prove the statement labeled as (1) in the proof of the proposition in the image?**

In the underlined area in the image below, how did the author conclude that each $f_{n}$ is Borel measurable?

The underlined part is already answered in a another question.

> $\quad$ **Proposition E.2.**
>
> $\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr A)$ be a measurable space, let $E$ be a Banach space, and let $f:X\to E$ be strongly measurable. Then there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of strongly measurable simple functions such that
>
> $\qquad\qquad f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_nf(x)$
>
> and
>
> $\qquad\qquad|f_n(x)|\leq|f(x)|,\ \ \ \ n=1,2,...,$
>
> hold at each $x$ in $X$.
>
> $\quad$ ***Proof.*** We can certainly assume that $f(X)$ contains at least one non-zero element of $E$. Let $C$ be a countable dense subset of $f(X)$, let $C^\sim$ be the set of rational multiples of elements of $C$, and let $\{y_n\}$ be an enumeration of $C^\sim$. We can assume that $y_1=0$. It is easy to check (do so) that
>
> **(1)** for each $y$ in $f(X)$ and each positive number $\epsilon$ there is a term $y_m$ of $\{y_n\}$ that satisfies $|y_m|\leq|y|$ and $|y_m-y|<\epsilon$.
>
> For each $x$  in $X$ and each positive integer $n$ define a subset $A_n(x)$ of $E$ by
>
> $\qquad\qquad A_n(x)=\{y_j:j\leq n\ \ \ {\rm and}\ \ \ |y_j|\leq|f(x)|\}.$
>
> Since $y_1=0$, each $A_n(x)$ is non-empty.
>
> $\quad$ We now construct the required sequence $\{f_n\}$ by letting $f_n(x)$ be the element of $A_n(x)$ that lies closest to $f(x)$ (in case
>
> **(2)** $\quad\quad|f(x)-y_j|=\inf\{|f(x)-y_i|:y_i\in A_n(x)\}$
>
> holds for several elements $y_j$ of $A_n(x)$, let $f_n(x)$ be $y_{j_0}$, where $j_0$ is the smallest value of $j$ for which $y_j$  belongs to $A_n(x)$ and satisfies (2)) It is clear that each $f_n$ is a simple function and that $|f_n(x)|\leq|f(x)|$ holds for each $n$ and $x$. $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{Since the sets $\{x\in X:f_n(x)=y_j\}$ can be described}}}}$ $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{by means of inequalities involving $|f(x)|$, $|y_i|$, $i=1,...,n$,}}}}$ $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{and $|f(x)-y_i|$, $i=1,...,n$, each $f_n$ is strongly measurable.}}}}$ Finally, observation (1) abov implies that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$ (if $y_m$ satisfies the inequalities $|y_m|\leq|f(x)|$ and $|y_m-f(x)|<\epsilon$, then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ holds whenever $n\geq m$). $\blacksquare$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you name the reference, please?

Comment: Do you need to know (a) how the set can be described by inequalities (b) why the set is measurable then or (c) why it follows from this that the function is strongly measurable?

Comment: Measure Theory by Donald L. Cohn. page 351

Comment: I think the answer is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324030/how-can-i-prove-that-this-simple-function-is-borel-measurable)

Comment: Do you have a wiki account? I suggest you add this book as reference there. *(There's almost no textbook at all that treats the Bochner integral.)*

Comment: Yes. Besides thanks for the reference! :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have such an account and you are welcome.

Comment: Never mind! ;) *(I did it now.)*

Comment: This is similar enough to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046192/bochner-integral-approximability) to have a duplicate answer. Perhaps this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

*Let me try a similar route...*

Enumerate a countable dense set:
$$\#S\leq\mathfrak{n}:\quad S=\{s_1,\ldots\}\quad(\overline{S}=F\Omega)$$

Regard the finite subsets:
$$S_K:=\{s_1,\ldots,s_K\}$$

Construct the domains by:
$$A_k:=A_n(s_k):=\{\omega:\|s_k\|\leq\|F(\omega)\|\}\cap\{\omega:\|F(\omega)-s_k\|<\tfrac{1}{n}\}$$

And sum up their disjoint parts:
$$A_k':=A_k\setminus\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^{k-1}A_l\right):\quad F_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{K=n}s_k\chi_{A_k'}$$
*(Note that the supports are clearly measurable.)*

Comment: Since you've copied your answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046192/bochner-integral-approximability), I assume the questions are very close, if not duplicates. If that is so, it would be better to close this question as a duplicate of the other instead of duplicating effort.

Comment: @robjohn: Right, though the questions are not identical they're still the same subject. What do you think: Closing? *(Note also that this question offers the solution to the other one.)*

Comment: @robjohn: However, it is for sure a duplicate of this thread: [How can I prove that this simple function is Borel measurable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/324030/79762)

Comment: How to prove the statement labeled as (1) in the proof of the proposition in the image?

Comment: @user28083: Try having a look into the proof above. Then you might understand also the idea of the original proof and figure out the measurability of the supports. In fact, originally it is done a little bit double around the corner. Let me know if you're still stuck, please!!

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea about these supports, because we haven't studied any thing about them. I think that the statement in (1) can be proved via basic arguments using the density and the set of rational numbers.

Comment: @user28083: Ok the basic idea of the original proof and the one above is to construct domains (supports) that are disjoint and where the values of the dense set have norm less than the function and also are close enough around the function. Up to that point both proofs agree more or less. However the original proof instead of choosing those points where this holds it selects those numbers which do so. $A(\omega):=\{\ldots\}$ vs. $A(s_k):=\{\ldots\}$ Can you imagine how to proceed then? Choosing the former makes it measurability obvious.

Comment: @Freeze_S: How to make sure that $A_{n}(s_{k})$ is not empty?

Comment: @user28083 Being empty is not a problem those ones simply won't be considered and in fact there will be tones never being touched. Important however is that the sequence approximates. That is guaranteed by the first property in the original proof (1).

Comment: @Freeze_S: But what I am asking about is how to prove (1) in the original proof.

Comment: @user28083: Ah ok sorry big missunderstanding. ^^ *(A moment, please.)*

Comment: @user28083: Suppose there's a ball with no points inside having norm less than that of its center. Take the ball with half the radius and center half the radius closer to the origin. Then it has no points inside at all. That is a contradiction to denseness. *(Draw a picture.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S: Sorry, could not understand it. It is getting late for me. Good night and thank you very much.

Comment: @user28083: No problem glad I could help and good night. :)